# Find the roots of the polynomial $x^4+2x^3-x-1=0$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, contest-math, roots

**Problem**
Find all $4$ roots of the polynomial: $$f(x)=x^4+2x^3-x-1.$$

---

**My Attempt**
Observe,
$$f(-2)=1,\; f(-1)=-1,\; f(0)=-1,\; f(1)=1.$$
Therefore, $f(x)$ has a root between $-2$ and $-1$, another root between $0$ and $1$.

Since $f(x)$ does not contain a second degree term, a clever substitution might change $f(x)$ into a polynomial that is easier to deal with. For example $(x\to x-1)$,
$$f(x-1)=x^4-2x^3+x-1=f(-x)$$
Also, I am avoiding computational or graphical assistance.

Comment: You have proved that if $a$ is a root, then so is $b=-a-1$. Therefore, try quadratic factors of the form $x^2+x+c$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With the substitution $x=t-b/na$, you eliminate the second highest order term of a polynomial $ax^n + bx^{n-1} + \cdots .$

If you substitute $x=t-2/4 = t-1/2$ your polynomial becomes

$$t^4 -\frac{3}{2}t^2 -\frac{11}{16}.$$

This is quadratic in $t^2$ so you can solve to get

$$t^2 = \frac{3\pm 2\sqrt{5}}{4}.$$

So the four roots of your polynomial are plus and minus the square roots of those two solutions (plus $1/2$ because of the original substitution.)  We were lucky that the first order term also disappeared.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** From your observation $f(x-1)=f(-x)$, it is clear $x=-\frac12$ is a point of symmetry.  Hence use $y=x+\frac12$ to get an even quadratic in $y$, which will then admit the substitution $t=y^2$ to solve...

Comment: Yes, should have explicitly worked it out and checked rather than made a quick hint.  Point of symmetry $=((x-1)+(-x))/2=-\frac12$.

Comment: I mentally rewrote $f(x-1)=f(-x)$ as $f(x)=f(1-x)$ myself (and had to delete a comment "correcting" lhf's comment below the OP when I realize how wrong I was).

Answer (score 1):

$(x^2+x)^2-(x^2+x)-1=0$ hence $x^2+x = \dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} \ $ or $\ x^2+x = \dfrac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

We can use the Bisection Method to approximate one of the solutions. The Bisection Method is an iterative procedure to approximate a root (Root is another name for a solution of an equation).
The function is $F(x)=x^{4}+2 x^{3}-x-1$

At $x=-1.00 \quad F(x)$ is equal to $-1.00$

At $x=-2.00 \quad F(x)$ is equal to $1.00$

Intuitively we feel, and justly so, that since $F(x)$ is negative on one side of the interval, and positive on the other side then, somewhere inside this interval, $F(x)$ is zero

Procedure:
(1) Find a point "Left" where $F($ Left $)<0$

(2) Find a point 'Right' where $F($ Right $)>0$

(3) Compute 'Middle' the middle point of the interval [Left,Right]

(4) Calculate Value $=F$ (Middle)

(5) If Value is close enough to zero goto Step (7)

Else:

If Value $<0$ then : Left <- Middle

If Value $>0$ then : Right $<-$ Middle

(6) Loop back to Step (3)

(7) Done!! The approximation found is Middle

Follow Middle movements to understand how it works:

$\begin{array}{rrrrr}\text { Left } & \text { Value(Left) } & \text { Right } & \text { Value (Right) } \\ -1.000000000 & -1.000000000 & -2.000000000 & 1.000000000 \\ 0.000000000 & -1.000000000 & -2.000000000 & 1.000000000 \\ -1.000000000 & -1.000000000 & -2.000000000 & 1.000000000 \\ -1.500000000 & -1.187500000 & -2.000000000 & 1.000000000 \\ -1.750000000 & -0.589843750 & -2.000000000 & 1.000000000 \\ -1.750000000 & -0.589843750 & -1.875000000 & 0.051025391 \\ -1.812500000 & -0.303939819 & -1.875000000 & 0.051025391 \\ -1.843750000 & -0.135573387 & -1.875000000 & 0.051025391 \\ -1.859375000 & -0.044614732 & -1.875000000 & 0.051025391 \\ -1.859375000 & -0.044614732 & -1.867187500 & 0.002612356 \\ -1.863281250 & -0.021148454 & -1.867187500 & 0.002612356 \\ -1.865234375 & -0.009304987 & -1.867187500 & 0.002612356 \\ -1.866210938 & -0.003355566 & -1.867187500 & 0.002612356 \\ -1.866699219 & -0.000373919 & -1.867187500 & 0.002612356 \\ -1.866699219 & -0.000373919 & -1.866943359 & 0.001118640\end{array}$

Next Middle will get us close enough to zero:
$$
F(-1.866760254) \text { is }-0.000000888
$$
The desired approximation of the solution is:
$$
x \risingdotseq-1.866760254
$$

After finding the approximate first solution for $x$, by factoring out, one can approximate the other $2$ solutions.

$\textbf{Note:}$ $\risingdotseq$ is the approximation symbol

Answer (score 0):

The "basic" tools for dealing with a polynomial with integer coefficients tell us that the zeroes will not be simple to locate.  The Rational Zeroes Theorem only suggests the candidates $ \ \pm 1 \ \ , $ which you have already shown are not correct.  The Rule of Signs indicates one positive real and three or one negative real zeroes.  We may suspect that two of the zeroes form a "complex conjugate pair", since the function is not positive for values $ \ -1 \ < \ x \ < \ 0 \ \ , $ as    $ \ x^4 - 1 \ $ is more negative in this interval than $ \ 2x^3 - x \ = \ x·(2x^2 - 1) \ $ is ever positive, so there are no further $ \ x-$intercepts.

We could naïvely factor the polynomial as  $ \ x^4 + 2x^3 - x - 1 \ = \ (x^2 + ax + b)·(x^2 + cx + d) \ \ , $ one of these factors being irreducible over real numbers. Following on your observation and **lhf**'s comment, it must be that each of these is the same under the transformations $ \ x \ \rightarrow \ -x \ $ and $ \ x \ \rightarrow \ x - 1 \ \ . $  [I am avoiding the implication of symmetry about $ \ x \ = \ -\frac12 \  , \ $ since **Macavity** and **B. Goddard** have already treated it.]  This will mean, for instance, that
$$ x^2 \ - \  ax \ + \ b \ \ = \ \ (x-1)^2 \ - \ a·(x-1) \ + \ b \ \ = \ \ x^2 \ + \ (a-2)·x \ + \ (b - a + 1) \ \ $$

$$ \Rightarrow \ \ -a \ \ = \ \ a \ - \ 2 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ a \ \ = \ \ 1 \ \ , $$
with $ \ b \ $ remaining unspecified.  The product of the factors is then
$$ (x^2 + x + b)·(x^2 + x + d) \ \ = \ \ x^4 \ + \ 2x^3 \ + \ (b + d + 1)·x^2 \ + \ (b + d)·x \ + \ bd \ \ . $$

This presents us with the coefficient equations $ \ b + d + 1 \ = \ 0 \ $ and $ \ b + d \ =  \ -1 \ \ , $ from the quadratic and linear terms, and $ \ bd \ = \ -1 \ \   $ as the constant term.  Putting these together, we find
$$ ( b \ + \  d )^2 \  = \  1 \ \ , \ \ 4bd \  = \  -4 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ (b \ - \ d)^2 \  = \  5 $$
$$ \Rightarrow \ \  b \ + \ d  \  = \  -1  \ \ \text{[as already determined]} \ \ , \ \ b \ - \ d \ = \ \pm \sqrt5 $$
$$ \Rightarrow \ \ b \ = \ \frac12 · (-1 \ \mp \ \sqrt5) \ \ , \ \ d \ = \ \frac12 · (-1 \ \pm \ \sqrt5) \ \ . $$

This makes it clear why a straightforward application of the Viete relations, or even an attempt to solve directly for the coefficients in $ \ x^4 + 2x^3 - x - 1 \ = \ (x^2 + ax + b)·(x^2 + cx + d) \ , \  $ is not very enlightening.  The factors may be written in either order, so, for instance,
$$   \left( \ x^2 + x - \frac12 · [1 \ + \ \sqrt5] \ \right) \ · \ \left( \ x^2 + x - \frac12 · [1 \ - \ \sqrt5] \ \right)  \ \ = \  \ 0 \ \ ,   $$
the zeroes of the first factor being the real values $ \ -\frac12 \ \pm \ \frac{\sqrt{3 \ +  \ 2·\sqrt5}}{2} \ \ \approx \ \ 0.8668 \ , \ -1.8668 \ $ and those of the second factor are the "conjugate pair" $ \ -\frac12 \ \pm \ i·\frac{\sqrt{2·\sqrt5 \ - \ 3}}{2} \ \ \approx \ \ -0.5 \ \pm \ i·0.6067 \ \ . $